# Test if kaminari params exist using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, kaminari

I'm new to Ruby, and my task is to add pagination for the get method, but I try to test if the params (page) and(per_page) exist, if they dont exist it should return all the data in the database, because by defaulkt kaminari return only the 25 page.

this is my function

```
def index
  if page.present? && per_page.present?
    @domains = Domain.accessible_by(access_token).page(page).per(per_page)
  else
    @domain = Domain.accessible_by(access_token).all
  end
  render json: @domain
end
```

at it return a `200 OK` response but null

Comment: In the else part of the statement you're assigning to `@domain` instead of `@domains` however you always render `@domain`

Comment: Where is `page` and `per_page` defined? In the gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller method receives request parameters via `params` object. Variables `page` and `per_page` are undefined which will throw an exception `undefined local variable, etc.`.

A few more things:

- I guess that `@domain` variable is a misprint and `@domains` should be used instead.
- Since both expressions of `if` fork return a value assigning to `@domains` variable, it can be simplified.

To sum up, here is improved controller method:

```
def index
  @domains = if params[:page].present? && params[:per_page].present?
               Domain.accessible_by(access_token)
                     .page(params[:page])
                     .per(params[:per_page])
             else
               Domain.accessible_by(access_token).all
             end

  render json: @domains
end
```

Comment: thanks, its working, but still I'm in the problem that kaminari return only 25  page per default

Comment: You could change it in initializer: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#general-configuration-options